# Find characters outside specified character range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I want to find characters that are not allowed in a column. Allowed chars are:

A-Z
0-9
Space (CHAR 32)
- (CHAR 45)

So everything else is not allowed in a VARCHAR column RegNo.
But problem is that during the past years there was no filtering in input.
So all kind of strange characters have been stored in database.

I want to find those cases and fix it.
So my first attempt

```
select regno from vehicle where regno like '%[^A-Z][^0-9][^-][^' + char(32) + ']%'
```

Result

```
Wiiks Luleå
SCÖ-01
NCÅ-01
668 AOJ
016 KMW
049 KMW
```

So first line is ok as it contains 'å'

But why 668 AOJ, 016 KMW, 049 KMW

Answer (score 4):

You're using the character classes incorrectly. For example `%[^A-Z][^0-9]%` will match `x y`  where space matches `[^A-Z]` and y matches `[^0-9]`. Combine them together like:

```
WHERE RegNo LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9\- ]%' ESCAPE '\'
WHERE RegNo LIKE '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9\- ]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Notes:

- The characters `^-]` should be escaped when used inside `[]`
- The character range could include additional characters such as accents. Specify a set instead of range if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here.  First, you should be using a single regex character class, not several of them, which are attempting to match several different characters.  Next, your range itself has an issue.  Try this version:

```
SELECT regno
FROM vehicle
WHERE regno LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ' + CHAR(32) + '-' + CHAR(44) + '-]%';
```

For an explanation of the above range, it matches any `regno` which has a character which is *not* an uppercase letter, number, space, or is in the range `CHAR(32) - CHAR(44)`.  Note that `CHAR(45)` itself is a hyphen, which we can place at the very range of the range to include it.

### Demo

Note that in the above demo only the final record does not match your pattern.